# Difference of same but undefined limit

Tags: limits

Say there is some function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$ is undefined. How would

$$
\lim_{x \to a} f(x) - \lim_{x \to a} f(x)
$$

be defined?

For example, consider

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x - \lim_{x \to \infty} \cos x
$$

On one hand, this could be considered as being in $[-2,2]$, but if the limit maintained linearity in this case, the limit of the difference could be taken and is 0.

Comment: $0$ is indeed on $[-2,2]$.

Comment: Perhaps considering $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ would scratch your itch. They are something of a step in the direction you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be undefined, since it is written as a difference of two undefined expressions.

It is often tempting, but just as often incorrect, to assume that you can push "$\lim$" around as you please. That's simply incorrect without justification (continuity, etc.). Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Regarding your example, it is definitely *NOT* valid to assume that you can interchange the subtraction and the limit process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some misunderstanding of **limit theorem for summation**. The theorem states that if the following holds

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } f(x) = A  \cr 
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } g(x) = B \cr} $$

i.e., the limits of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist, then the limit of the summation is

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left( {f(x) + g(x)} \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } f(x) + \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } g(x)$$

But the vice-versa is not true. Specifically, if the limit of the summation of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ exist, it doesn't guarantee the existence of individual limits of them.

Comment: I'm aware that the reverse is not true, and it would be clear in the case you gave provided $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ are not the same. I was wondering if there was a way this could be manipulated when they are the same and a difference is being taken rather than a sum such that the limit would be defined in this particular case.

Comment: The sum isn't a big deal, the theorem can be proved for subtraction. Also, the theorem holds regardless of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ being the same or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be undefined as the normal interpretation of an expression is that it will be evaluated in parts. For example $f(x)-f(x)$ means that we first evaluate $f(x)$ and then insert that result in place of the $f(x)$'s and then evaluates the difference.

For the expression $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) - \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ the evaluation order is the same, but you would fail to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ so you can't complete the evaluation.

It may be tempting to fiddle with this way of evaluating expression which might make it possible to allow for otherwise undefined expressions to be defined, but I doubt that it would be worth the problem (and I guess that it would be quite a task to build such a framework).